# How to configure Azure VM for SSIS package using FTP task

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssis, ftp

I have created my Windows Azure VM from the Gallery using the WS 2012 + SQL 2012 image.

I am doing a POC using SSIS to pull files from an FTP site and load into my database.  I am having a problem with the FTP task inside SSIS. The files I am pulling are plain text, so I've set my transfer mode to ascii in my SSIS package.  My problem comes when I try to navigate to the remote path.  I get the following error:

> Error: An error occurred in the requested FTP operation. Detailed error description: 200 Type set to A.
>
> 500 Invalid PORT Command.
>   500 'LPRT 6,16,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,42,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,192,34': command not understood

If I type in the remote path and try to execute the package, I get the same error.  I have created an FTP Endpoint for my VM using 22 as public and 21 as private ports.  Is there something else I need to do to get this work?

I've found lots of articles on how to configure FTP services for an Azure VM, but that's not what I want to do.  I want to run a SSIS package that uses an FTP task.

Answer (score 0):

did you check the machines Firewall rules too? 
can you execute the frp command normally outside of the SSIS task (ie browser, cmdline or ftp client) ?

Comment: I am able to verify FTP connection and transfer files via Browser (IE) and FileZilla on my Azure VM.  However I cannot get files to transfer via a command prompt, but I can connect and navigate remote directory structure. 

I have not made any changes to the firewall rules on the Azure VM.

Comment: One other interesting tidbit, the command line works just fine on my local machine.  I can connect, navigate and download files.

Comment: Messed with firewall rules until I was blue in the face.  Never could get the native FTP task to work.  I did however, write a Script Task and got it work on the first try.  A bit disappointed that I couldn't get the native FTP task to work though.